# Get items from list filtering by ids

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, sharepoint-rest-api, microsoft-graph

I would like to get items from list filter by ids through **Microsoft Graph Api**.

Something like `items?$filter=fields/id eq '3' or '4' or '5'`. I have to get many elements and I want limit requests.

Is there any way to do something like that?

Comment: Im having a hard time understanding your question about limit requests. Could you elaborate?

Comment: I want to get a list of items based on the given id list. If the id list has 20 elements, I wanted to avoid calling the getById method 20 times only to do one query and download all elements at once.

Answer (score 2):

Just using

```
/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('TestList')/items?$filter=Id eq '3' or Id eq '4' or Id eq '5'
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it you would like to filter for multiple items using their ids? In that case you can do this by performing this query in this format:

```
items?$filter=fields/id eq '3' or fields/id eq '4' or fields/id eq '5'
```

However there seems to be an problem doing this with the graph api and SharePoint list items. So im not sure that this answers your question.

However there are multiple ways of doing this and the best way to learn is to have a look at the docs to see what query options you can perform. [Use query parameters to customize responses](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters) and more specific [$filter](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#filter-parameter).

Comment: I wanted do the same way as you wrote in example ("items?$filter=fields/id eq '3' or fields/id eq '4' or fields/id eq '5"). But after this request in response preview i have:     "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "Invalid filter clause",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "bdedd6ba-3ba0-4c07-8f67-ad0b9d46ceff",
            "date": "2019-11-19T15:28:01"
        }
    }. 
I couldn't find anything similar in the documentation. That's why I ask because I was surprised by the lack of such functionality.